# What data type should I be using to represent Time (not dateTime) in an xsd/xml?

Tags: xml, xsd

I what to represent just time in xsd. So i can say current date +  time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are all valid:

- `xs:time`
- `xs:date`
- `xs:dateTime`

Pick whichever one is appropriate for you.

Answer (score 0):

xs:time should work for you,

if you wish to define your own datatype then that is also most welcome.

Define a **simpleType** with a custom name and namespace in the same xsd file or define it in an external xsd file and include that xsd file.

```
<xs:simpleType name="CRNDATETIME">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="(01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12)[:][0-5][0-9][:][0-5][0-9] [aApP][mM]))"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

this will accept time in format `HH:MM:SS TT` example :: `01:07:59 AM` or `01:07:59  am`

in similar way you can define 24 hours time too :)

regards,
Infant Pro